# how to detect number of contours in between two lines or specified region of image

Tags: c++, opencv3.0, object-detection

I am using OpenCV C++ to find the contours in a video. I want to count the no of contours present in video in a a specified region or in between two lines drawn in a video. For example a stream of contours are moving in a video and I want to count them when they reach to a specific region in a video. I will decrease the count as they leave the specific region in the video. I know some basic stuffs to find contour, calculate the area etc. But I am not getting any programming tips to count the no of contours within specified region. Please help me with the related topics and some tips on programming. (I do not want to use cvBlob.h library)

Basically I am counting the number of cars entered in that region. If car is entered I will increment the count and if it leaves the region then I will decrease the count.

[image]

Comment: Please help us to help you, including some images, the expected results, and the code you have.

Comment: @Miki I have updated the question and image.

Comment: Your regions can be modeled as 1) `Rect`, or 2) masks. In case 1) you can check whether each point of the contour (or only the centroid) falls into a rect. You can use `rect.contains(point)` for this. If you have a mask, where each region has a label number, you can check the labels for each point of the contour (or the centroid)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can approximate the contour you found to a polygon or circle:

```
for( int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++ )
 { approxPolyDP( Mat(contours[i]), contours_poly[i], 3, true );
   boundRect[i] = boundingRect( Mat(contours_poly[i]) )
 }
```

after that use the line equation `y=a` and compare the coordinates of the corners of rectangle or the `center+radius` of the circle to determine if the contour passed the line.

Comment: thank you very much. I got some clue to my question. Could you please tell me how to keep track of the object. Suppose if 2 or 3 cars are moving it should keep track of each and every car.

Comment: It really depends on your problem, how complicated your background is . The easiest choice is using [camshift](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html#camshift) or [meanshift](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html#meanshift) , there are tones of tutorial about them and for your case it's easy to use since they accept a rectangle & track that rectangle in video. If they didn't work you can try Kalman Filter or TLD.

Comment: @pradeep please accept the answer if it helped you :) thanks

Comment: updated the image. Please have a look at it once and advice me accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

1.Use a part of your Mat image.(If your ROI is rectangle)

```
Mat src;  // suppose this is your source frame
Mat src_of_interest = src(Rect(Point(x1, y1), Point(x2, y2)));

// Do the rest of finding contour..

vector<vector<Point>> contours;
vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;

findContours(src_of_interest.clone(), contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

//now you can do your job with contour vector.    
int count = contours.size();

Mat dst = Mat::zeros(src.size(), CV_8UC3);
for(int i=0; i< count; i++)
{
    drawContours(dst, contours, i, CV_RGB(255, 0, 0));   // draw contour in red
}
```

2. If your Region of Interest is not rectangle, try this approach:

```
vector<Point> contour_of_interest;   // this contour is where you want to check
vector<vector<Point>> contours;   // this is the contours you found

Mat dst = Mat::zeros(src.size(), CV_8U);
for(int i=0; i< count; i++)
{
    drawContours(dst, contours, i, Scalar(255));   // set contour area to 255
}

Mat roi = Mat::zeros(src.size(), CV_8U);
vector<vector<Point>> coi_vector;
coi_vector.push_back(contour_of_interest);
drawContours(roi, coi_vector, 0, Scalar(255));

Mat and = dst & roi;    // where 2 mats are both TRUE(not zero)

findContours(and.clone(), contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

//now you can do your job with contour vector.    
int count = contours.size();
```

3. If you want to count contours between 4 points, try this approach:

```
vector<Point> contour_of_interest;   // this contour is the area where you want to check
Point p1(x1, y1);
Point p2(x1, y2);
Point p3(x2, y2);
Point p4(x2, y1);
contour_of_interest.push_back(p1);
contour_of_interest.push_back(p2);
contour_of_interest.push_back(p3);
contour_of_interest.push_back(p4);

vector<vector<Point>> coi_list;
coi_list.push_back(contour_of_interest);

Mat mask = Mat:zeros(src.size(), CV_8U);
drawContours(mask, coi_list, 0, Scalar(255));

Mat src;  // suppose this is your source frame
Mat src_of_interest = src & mask;  // remove any pixels outside mask area

// Do the rest of finding contour..

vector<vector<Point>> contours;
vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;

findContours(src_of_interest.clone(), contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

//now you can do your job with contour vector.    
int count = contours.size();

Mat dst = Mat::zeros(src.size(), CV_8UC3);
for(int i=0; i< count; i++)
{
    drawContours(dst, contours, i, CV_RGB(255, 0, 0));   // draw contour in red
}
```

Comment: I have updated the new image. The style of programming is good. I would like to use same in my program. Could you please help me rewrite the program according to the new image that I have updated. I want to know the direction of the contours, for that I have to use two lines. Please not that I am not using any rectangles. I want to count the contours if it enters the two lines. I hope you understood the scenario. Please let me know if it is not clear.

Comment: @pradeep exactly what do x1, x2, x3, x4 and y1, y2, y3, y4 mean? In your picture there are only 2 y-coordinates.

Comment: @pradeep I added 3rd method and I think you can apply it.

Comment: Thank you, I named the co-ordinates wrong. But caught it. I will implement it and get back to you.

Comment: @pradeep There were some syntax error, I edited 3rd one. Check it out.

Comment: I will test this code and get back to you. Need some time.